# Dropzone js/ Removing Images not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i uploaded multiple images via dropzone.js & i want to remove some images then its removeing on client side but its not remove from data-base. i wrote following code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){     alert("ssss");
   jQuery(".dz-remove").on("click", function (event) {   
   var edit_field = this;
   var _mainimagename = jQuery(this).parent().find('.dz-image').find('img').attr('alt');
       var _product_id_imp =   jQuery("input[name='product_ids']").val();   
            $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "drag-dropdelete.php",
               data: {row_id : _mainimagename,p_id : _product_id_imp},
               success: function (data) {
                 if (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    //window.location.reload();
                 }
              }
         });
    });
});  `
```